# Printing from 1 to 99 using a print and for loop function

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I tried the following in the IDLE of Python 3.6

```
print(value for value in range(1,100))
```

A message is produced in the IDLE which says

`<generator object <genexpr> at 0x101b73a40>`

I'm confused what this means. Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Alternatively, just wrap your statement with `list(..)`. `print(list(value for value in range(1,100)))`. I should mention vanilla list comprehensions are actually faster than calling `list(..)`.

Comment: Maybe you meant `(print value) for value in range(1, 100)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(value for value in range(1,100))` produces `generator` object, if you want to print `list`, just wrap it in `[]`

```
print([value for value in range(1,100)])
```

or you can simply

```
print(list(range(1,100)))
```

You can read what generators are [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator)

> A function which returns a generator iterator. It looks like a normal function except that it contains yield expressions for producing a series of values usable in a for-loop or that can be retrieved one at a time with the next() function.
>
> Usually refers to a generator function, but may refer to a generator iterator in some contexts. In cases where the intended meaning isn’t clear, using the full terms avoids ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

```
print([value for value in range(1,100)])
```

You should include it inside a list `[]` to generate the values

Answer (score 0):

All you wanted is to use list comprehension here but you are not using list.
Simply it should be

```
for i in range(1,100):
    print(i)
```

If you want to still use list comprehension it will be like this

```
[print(x) for x in range(1,100)]
```

this will give the output like

```
1
2
3
....
99
100
[None, None, None, ...97 times more]
```